# I cannot import pygame.mixer

Tags: python, pygame

I've been getting into programming and started doing the online course "Program Arcade Games" on my MacBook Pro to learn how to program basic game logic in `pygame`. I've run into a problem at [Chapter 11.](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=bitmapped_graphics_and_sound&lang=en)

I'm supposed to use the `pygame.mixer.Sound` function to create a sound effect that will later be activated on mouse click. The whole program can be found [here](http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=bitmapped_graphics_and_sound&lang=en) under Section 11.5. The issue is, whenever I run the code, Terminal outputs the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/EffingLame/mystuff/Lab10.py", line 30, in <module>
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, GRAY, [x+3,y+3,100,100]) #Head
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 105, in __getattr__
    raise NotImplementedError(MissingPygameModule)
builtins.NotImplementedError: mixer module not available
(ImportError: No module named 'pygame.mixer')
```

I've entered the code exactly as it was presented on the website, and eventually copy and pasted the entire program when that didn't work, so faulty code shouldn't be the issue. More likely, something wasn't implemented correctly when I downloaded `pygame`, right?

Right now, my strongest theory is that some how `sdl_mixer` was incorrectly installed. When I've tried to reinstall the files, I'm always given an "Empty Installation" error.

I've searched around for this quite a bit, and so far I'm beginning to worry that I'm the only one with this problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Important Info:

```
Using OSX Yosemite

Using python 3.5.1

Using pygame 1.9.1
```

Homebrew was used to install `pygame` and its support files

What I've already tried:

Reinstalling `sdl_mixer` with `libvorbis` (However, when ever I reinstall, I get the error message: `"Error: Empty Installation"`)

Reinstalling python 3 and `pygame`

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned using homebrew to install "pygame and its support files" but not how you installed Python itself.  You need to install Python via homebrew as well, so that all the file locations will be consistent.  Remove your previous python3 and run `brew install python3`.